# How to resolve 'User load segfault' error with RISC-V spike -m option?

Tags: riscv

RISC-V spike -m option not working as expected

I am using the following simple C program to test the RISC-V spike -m memory region option

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Memory region test\n");
    printf("Memory read: %d\n", *(int*)(0xFFFFf000));
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following script to compile the program and run it on spike:

```
FILE=memtest
isa=rv32imc_zicsr_zifencei
march=-march=$isa
mabi=-mabi=ilp32
riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -save-temps=obj -o $FILE  $FILE.c  $march $mabi  -Wa,$march -Wa,$mabi -O0 -g -Xlinker -Map=$FILE.map 
../riscv-isa-sim/build/spike  -m0x80000000:0x400000,0xFFFFf000:0x1000 --isa=$isa  ../bin/pk $FILE
```

spike produces the following output:

```
bbl loader
Memory region test
z  00000000 ra 00010158 sp 7ffffd90 gp 0001f810
tp 00000000 t0 00000005 t1 00000003 t2 00000000
s0 7ffffda0 s1 00000000 a0 0000000a a1 0001fa40
a2 00000013 a3 00000013 a4 00000001 a5 fffff000
a6 00000002 a7 00000040 s2 00000000 s3 00000000
s4 00000000 s5 00000000 s6 00000000 s7 00000000
s8 00000000 s9 00000000 sA 00000000 sB 00000000
t3 00000400 t4 00000000 t5 00000000 t6 00008803
pc 0001015a va/inst fffff000 sr 80006020
User load segfault @ 0xfffff000
```

Are there additional initialization needed, e.g. configuration of the MMU?